# How to hook "/system/ajax" with javascript in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

When a field accepts multiple values, the admin form adds a button "Add another item". Mousedown submits a POST to /system/ajax to get another field (i'm using multifield here).

I'd like to hook into the javascript completed event to do some custom handling on those additional fields.

[image]

How can I most easily hook these ajax calls for javascript callback and reference to the block being added? Is it possible without PHP?

Comment: Not sure if Drupal raises an event, but if not you could always use `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) { .. }`

Comment: @Clive, is there a better way to ID the original button clicked? I'm basically parsing the response for a string i'm familiar with in this block. Then doing a bunch more to check for attributes i'll manage as HTML is added and removed:

Comment: `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,xhr,settings){
   if (settings.url.indexOf("/system/ajax") > -1) {
    var data = xhr.responseText;
    if (data) {
     data = JSON.parse(data);
     if (data.length > 0 && typeof data[1].data != 'undefined') {
      data = data[1].data;
      if (data.indexOf('field-search-radius') > -1) {
       console.log('i found you!');
      }
     } 
    }
   }
  });`

Comment: Client-side only? I don't think there is - you'd need to hook into the form ajax in PHP

Answer (score -1):

You can use `hook_menu_alter` and define your own custom callback function like below.

```
function demo_pane_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['system/ajax']['page callback'] = 'demo_pane_taxonomy_autocomplete';
}
```

Comment: Won't this break all Ajax operations?